# Persist IndexedDB even after computer restart in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, indexeddb, electron, dexie

I'm trying to use Dexie/indexedDB in an Angular 2 app that runs over Electron, the databases I created + data inserted persist after I restart the application, but if I restart the computer then all the data is erased.

Is there anyway to persist the data on the disk so it is available even after a computer restart?

How can I get a copy of the indexedDb and persist it in a file using NodeJS and then reload it?, is it possible?

Comment: What OS are you running? I'm also using IndexedDB with Electron, on Ubuntu 16.10, but for me the data is persisting even after restart (in `~/.config/[appname]/IndexedDB`)

Comment: I'm using Windows 10, I still don't chck in Ubuntu, I'll update this after some research.

Comment: I use indexedDB in my electron app and it persists after restart so far for all users apart from one. Also on windows 10. I cant seem to work out whats different about there set up. was your issue ever resolved?